# Abertura gaveta dinheiro

Tags: c#, wpf, relatório, impressora

Eu estou tentar enviar um comando para abrir minha gaveta de dinheiro automaticamente pela minha aplicação, mas sem exito até o momento.
Eu entrei em contato com a fabricante da gaveta e da impressora (Não fiscal) a Bematech e eles me indicaram um download com uma dll que tenho que usar e um arquivo info aonde tenho algumas informações que seguem abaixo...

---

Parâmetros:
Comando: STRING com o comando que deseja executar.
Tamanho do Comando: INTEIRO com o tamanho do comando que será enviado.

Exemplo:
' Exemplo em Visual Basic
' Comando para Acionar a Gaveta de Dinheiro
sComando = chr( 27 ) + chr( 118 ) + chr( 140 )
iRetorno = ComandoTX( sComando, Len( sComando )

// Exemplo em Delphi
// Comando para Acionar a Gaveta de Dinheiro

sComando := #27 + #118 + #140; 
iRetorno := ComandoTX( sComando, Length( sComando );

O retorno desta função é dado através de um valor inteiro, onde se o retorno for:
1 (um): Sucesso. A função foi executada sem problemas.

### 0 (zero): Erro na comunicação.

Mas agora eu estou com dificuldade de entender a lógica de como enviar esse comando para a impressora para ela abrir a gaveta. Eu posso enviar parecido como eu envio a impressão do recibo?

Exemplo de como eu imprimo...

```
insira o código aqui
                //--------------------------------Impressão do recibo ---------------------------//
                // popular relatório
                var report = from p in _objListProduct
                             select p;

                var rpDepartament = new crSaleDepartament();
                rpDepartament.SetDataSource(report);


                rpDepartament.SetParameterValue("NameUser", _nameUser);
                rpDepartament.SetParameterValue("NameDepartament", 

                //impressão direta do .rpt sem conversão
                rpDepartament.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui...

Classe

```
[DllImport("MP2032.dll")]
public static extern int ComandoTX(String comando, int tComando);

Chamei no botão              

const int charCode = 27;
const int charCode2 = 118;
const int charCode3 = 140;
var specialChar = Convert.ToChar(charCode);
var specialChar2 = Convert.ToChar(charCode2);
var specialChar3 = Convert.ToChar(charCode3);
string cmdText = "" + specialChar + specialChar2 + specialChar3;
iRetorno = MP2032.ComandoTX(cmdText, cmdText.Length);
```